# PhraseExpress slow to enter text

Tags: speed, phraseexpress

I’m using the latest version of PharseExpress and fully updated Windows 10.

The problem is that PhraseExpress types out the text in a relatively slow fashion (compared to when it just insert the entire chuck of text). This does not happen if there is a dropdown option in the phrase, or other WYSIWYG macros.
Is there a way to control this? I would like for the entire piece of text to just appear like it was passed in.

Link to YouTube video showing the “problem”: https://youtu.be/Qk67Ij6sPG4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PhraseExpress settings, you should make sure that the default settings for inserting text are enabled.

For texts with a length of more than 100 characters, PhraseExpress should use the clipboard by default. It should just paste the longish text that you show in the video, which would be faster.

Please make sure your settings are okay, otherwise just select "Reset Settings".

[image: PhraseExpress insertion settings]

You can also set paste options for individual programs or even snippets. There is a macro under Macros - Programming - Set paste method and speed.

If you want to use the clipboard for inserting a snippet, just paste `{#pasteoptions -method cb}` at the beginning of the snippet.

[image: Paste option for snippets]

Comment: Hi from the PhraseExpress makers, There is nothing to add to this superb answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was 100% sure that I had reset the settings!

Answer (score 1):

You apparently messed with the settings. Please read the fine manual:
http://www.phraseexpress.com/docs11/09/manual.htm#pastemethod

PhraseExpress offers several methods to paste text into a target application:

'Key-by-Key' simulation of individual key stroke: Suitable for short text without formatting. Simulating keystrokes begins instantly without delay but each keystroke takes a little time. You can actually watch how PhraseExpress "enters" the text for you. The longer the text, the longer it takes to insert it.

Windows clipboard: Must be used for formatted text or bitmaps. PhraseExpress copies the phrase into the clipboard, switches to the target application and triggers the clipboard to paste its contents into the target application. The clipboard can paste large chunks of text very fast but requires some time to be filled with contents.